# How best to connect a Windows 10 laptop to a RHEL 8 virtual machine?

Tags: windows, redhat, windows-10, rhel8, xrdp

I use a Windows 10 PC to log into and work on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 system every day.  I have been using xpra to talk to it.  Xpra dies every few minutes for a few seconds.  Very irritating.

I'm told that RHEL8 doesn't support xrdp.  Yes, I need X-Windows support.  I need to run a browser on the Linus system and interact with it from my Windows system.

Surely, somebody has already solved this problem.  What is a reliable solution to talk between Red Hat and a Windows system?  Thanks, Rick

Answer (score 0):

I use Xming (https://xming.en.softonic.com/), but there are any number of X-Windows applications for Windows.  VNC is another mechanism to get a similar type of interaction.

X passes a lot of traffic, so if you keep having connection issues, try using a wired ethernet connection rather than wifi.

Comment: Hi, Mike.   I can wire my laptop rather than use wifi.   The rest of it, I have no control.   Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, just as one more variable you can remove.